# Cannot set 'readonly' property using angular-ckeditor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I'm using this npm package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ckeditor in an AngularJs app with angular version 1.4.8.

I'm using the ckeditor directive like this:

```
        <div class="messaging-editor>
           <div ckeditor="ctrl.ckOptions" ng-model="ctrl.formData.email"></div>
        </div>
```

I need to be able to dynamically set the `readOnly` property for this editor based on a certain condition. I haven't been able to set the editor to `readOnly` by hardcoding it or by any means. Note: I tried both lowercase `readonly` as well as camelCase `readOnly`.

I've attempted to set the `readOnly` property in the `ctrl.ckOptions` object.

I've tried hardcoding it to true in the main config file.

I tried adding the `readonly` attribute to the `<div>` where the directive is being used.

I've also added a script directly to my template file to try to set the editor to `readOnly` on `instanceReady` event. I'm able to see the event fire and tried running `editor.setReadOnly(true)` but it remains false.

I've also tried this workaround I've found on other posts, though it wasn't for this node package specifically but ckeditor:

```
    editor.document.$.body.disabled = true;
    editor.document.$.body.contentEditable = false;
    editor.document.$.designMode="off";
```